# How to clear the user input on a GWT CellTable?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a `CellTable<Price> table = new CellTable<Price>();`.

I also have a `TextInputCell` column:

```
        priceColumn = new Column<Price, String>(new TextInputCell()) {
            public String getValue(Price p) {
                if (p.getPrice() == 0)
                    return "";
                return p.getPrice()+"";
            }   
        };
```

Also I have a `refresh button`. If the button is pressed, then it basically reload all data from server and then set the data to the table.

When the table first time load data, it is fine. Let's say, **a cell** has price of **12**.

Then if I modify that cell to **11 (or whatever value other than 12)**, then the `11` stays there forever. I mean, even if I press the `refresh button`, the cell's data will not change back to `12`, but still stay `11`.

**How can I make the column / cell not remembering the user input?**

Comment: What do you do when a user enters a new value?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin for now, nothing. I don't setFieldUpdater. But I may add one so that if the user's value fits certain conditions, I will update the price object.

Comment: Did you confirm that the new data arrived and refresh() was called? I never saw this problem with CellTable - the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin yes, I confirm it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you received the new data and updated your objects with the new data call `table.redraw();`

**Working example**

```
final Price p1 = new Price(4);
final Price p2 = new Price(5);
final Price p3 = new Price(6);

final CellTable<Price> table = new CellTable<Price>();

Column<Price, String> priceColumn = new Column<Price, String>(new TextInputCell()) {
    public String getValue(Price p) {
    if (p.getPrice() == 0)
        return "";
    return p.getPrice() + "";
    }
};

ListDataProvider<Price> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Price>();
dataProvider.addDataDisplay(table);

List<Price> list = dataProvider.getList();
list.add(p1);
list.add(p2);
list.add(p3);

table.addColumn(priceColumn);

Button b = new Button("refresh");
b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // your refresh logic, update the items already loaded into the CellTable!
    p2.setPrice(1000);
    p3.setPrice(2000);

    table.redraw();
    }
});

RootPanel.get().add(table);
RootPanel.get().add(b);
```

Comment: why did you vote for not useful? isn't this helping? If this is not the right answer than I guess your question is not clear - at least to me.